# Grails 3 saving mongoDB document with both _id and id

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

We noticed an issue after an upgrade to grails 3 that we were saving mongoDB documents with both `_id` and `id`. (example document below)

How do we stop the saving of `id`? This happens for every collection the application creates and updates documents for.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0ed1b710b3641a98aaee63"),
"value" : "testing",
"type" : "testingCreate",
"updateDate" : ISODate("2018-05-30T16:30:39.987Z"),
"updateUser" : "TSTUSR",
"id" : ObjectId("5b0ed1b710b3641a98aaee63")
}
```

The save is being called from the following

```
def test = new AppParam(type: "testingCreate",
                        updateUser: "TSTUSR", 
                        updateDate: new Date(), 
                        value: "testing")
test.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

for the appParam domain of

```
class AppParam {
ObjectId id
String type
String value
String updateUser
Date updateDate

static mapWith = "mongo"

static mapping = {
    version false
    writeConcern WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED
}

static constraints = {
    type size: 1..50, matches:/^[^<>]{1,50}$/, validator: { field, obj ->
        if (!field.trim()) return ['typeRequired']
        return true
    }
    value size: 1..2000, matches:/^[^<>]{1,2000}$/, validator: { field, obj ->
        if (!field.trim()) return ['valueRequired']
        return true
    }

}
}
```

We are using grailsVersion 3.2.11 and gormVersion 6.1.7.RELEASE

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant but when I upgraded from Grails 2 to 3 I had to set the engine to mapping as described in the persistence engine section a little further down in this link, http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#upgradeNotes, without this setting I had a number of issues with existing documents

Comment: Yeah, when we upgraded to Grails 3 we had to change the engine to mapping but didn't seem to affect this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a bit more research into Mike W's comment after Grails 3.X it should be defaulting the mongodb engine to codec and we were manually defaulting the mongodb.engine = "mapping".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the `mapping` closure.

```
static mapping {
    id column: '_id'
    version false
    writeConcern WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect anything, the documents are still saving both the `_id` and `id`

Comment: @DavidB You're right, it doesn't seem to affect anything. I built a test app with Grails 3.3.5 and with no modification to your `AppParam` domain, the resulting collection in mongo had only an `_id` property - no `id`. This is what you want, i think.

`gormVersion` is 6.1.9.RELEASE. mongodb plugin is at 6.1.5. Perhaps upgrading one or both of them will fix your issue.